# What's the difference between the commands "EditLinks" and "EditHyperlink" in Microsoft Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm creating customized keyboard shortcuts and I'm not sure which of these I should create a shortcut to. What I want is to hit the keyboard shortcut and be taken to the Hyperlink dialog box where I can add, remove, or edit a link on the selected word or object.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

"Links" are OLE Links to other MS office documents, whereas Hyperlinks are URIs to web based content. see here for information about linking to documents via OLE: http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010024_Working_with_Document_Links.html

So you want the EditHyperlinks command.